# Determining initial conditions for central force question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

> Question: A particle of unit mass is acted on by an attractive force of magnitude $k/r^2$ directed toward origin O. It is projected from infinity with speed $v$ along a line whose perpendicular distance from O is $d$. Find and sketch the path of the particle.

I know that since we have a central force,  $u''(\theta)$ + $u(\theta)$ = $k/h^2$ where $u = 1/r$ and $h$ is the angular momentum per unit mass, which is conserved.

However, I am really unsure what my initial conditions are from the information given. I don't quite understand what being projected "from infinity" means and how I am meant to determine $h$ or anything about $r(0)$ and  $\dot r(0)$. I would appreciate some help as to how to understand the scenario and hence derive the intial conditions for my ODE

Comment: What does $\theta$ stand for?

Comment: So (r,$\theta$) is polar coordinates where so r is magnitude from origin and $\theta$ is angle made with axis. Sorry for not making it clearer

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a reference for your DE in $u(\theta)$?

Comment: Yeah if you go to page 32 https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/IA_L/dynamics_and_relativity.pdf

Comment: From the solution of your differential equation you obtain that the path of the particle ()
 is ellipse , for that you don’t need the initial  conditions in time domain.

Answer (score 1):

You are given two quantities that are conserved throughout the motion:
(a) The mechanical energy $E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{k}{r}.$
(b) The angular momentum about the force center $L=mvd.$

Comment: I see that these quantities are conserved, although I don't know how they help me determine any initial conditions to solve the ODE. My main issue is knowing how to determine the eccentricity of my curve.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is projected from infinity with velocity, v, it starts with kinetic energy but zero potential energy. It will follow a hyperbolic curve which has a focus at the origin. As the potential energy goes negative, (-k/r) the kinetic will increase. It conserves both energy and angular momentum. At the point of minimum radius the velocity will be perpendicular to the radius. That should get you started.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand that $E = v^2/2$ is constant throughout the motion. However, I am unsure how to derive the initial conditions in order to show that the particle takes a hyperbolic curve. How would I determine the eccentricity from the fact that energy and angular momentum are conserved?

Comment: If by "initial conditions" you mean the eccentricity, then you are not given enough information to find it.  However, the fact that the particle is at infinity with non-zero speed suggests that it is not in a bound orbit.  I would pick a value greater than 1 for the eccentricity and sketch the path.

Comment: The total energy is constant: E = $v^2$/2 – k/r.  With angular momentum that should let you determine the minimum radius.